# Llenar los textbox según el valor del select

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

En la Imagen 1 el procedimiento almacenado que trae los datos de solicitud_titulo, solicitud_tipo y clientes_id , ya logro listar la solicitud titulo y seleccionar lo que quiero que al seleccionar se rellenen los texbox con los campos de solicitud_tipo y el cliente_id para luego usar el id del cliente para traer los datos del cliente.
Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la solicitud_titulo se llenen los campos los textbox con solicitud_tipo y el dato de cliente_id pero solo me lista pero no se llenan los otros campos a continuación mando mi codigo

[image: Tengo este procedimiento almacenado que trae esos datos]

[image: Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la solicitud_titulo se llenen los campos los textbox con solicitud_tipo y el dato de cliente_id pero solo me lista pero no se llenan los otros campos a continuación mando mi codigo]

```js
function listar_combo_solicitud(){
    $.ajax({
        "url":"../controlador/factura/controlador_combo_solicitud_listar.php",
        type:'POST'
    }).done(function(resp){
        var data = JSON.parse(resp);
        var cadena="";
        if(data.length>0){
            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                cadena+="<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#soli_titulo").html(cadena);
            $("#tipo_solicitud");
            $("#descripcion_solicitud");
            $("#nombre_cliente");
        }else{
            cadena+="<option value=''>NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS</option>";
        }
    })
```

```css
function listar_combo_solicitud(){
            $sql = "call SP_LISTAR_COMBO_SOLICITUD()";
            $arreglo = array();
            if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {
                while ($consulta_VU = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                        $arreglo[] = $consulta_VU;
                }
                return $arreglo;
                $this->conexion->cerrar();
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="">Seleccione la Solicitud de Trabajo</label>
                    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="soli_titulo" style="width:100%;">
                    </select><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="">Tipo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tipo_solicitud" MaxLength="35" disabled>
                    </select><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="">Descripcion</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion_solicitud" MaxLength="35" disabled>
                    </select><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="">Usuario ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_cliente" MaxLength="35" disabled>
                    </select><br>
                </div>
```

Comment: Haz la escucha del evento ```change``` del select y cada vez que haya cambios trae los datos según el contenido del select

Comment: y eso como se hace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer una llamada AJAX enviando el id de la solicitud, para hacer una consulta a la base de datos con ese ID y así, con los datos obtenidos, rellenar los inputs que quieres rellenar.

Muy por encima sería algo como:

```
$("#soli_titulo").change(function(){
//Esto se ejecutará cuando el select cambie de valor
$.ajax({
        "url":"../controlador/factura/archivo_php_en_el_que_se_hace_la_consulta.php",
        type:'GET',
        data: {
              "id": $("#soli_titulo").val()
        },
    }).done(function(resp){
        //Con los datos obtenidos rellenamos los campos, pongo solo un ejemplo, los datos reales a los que tienes que igualar dependerá del formato de los datos recibidos
        $("#tipo_solicitud").val(resp[0]);
        $("#descripcion_solicitud").val(resp[0]);
        $("#nombre_cliente").val(resp[0]);
    })
});
```

Obviamente también necesitarás un archivo php en el que realices la consulta a la base de datos con el ID enviado por el ajax.
Ten en cuenta que este código es solamente orientativo y tendrás que ver tú como realmente tiene que ser tu código para que te funcione según tu proyecto.